# How to enable server base custom plugin in ispconfig

Tags: plugins, ispconfig-3

I have created new server base custom plugin dymmy_function_plugin.inc.php under  /usr/local/ispconfig/server/plugins-available path.

I am new so I have no idea how to enable the new custom plugin to call on event.

Answer (score 1):

I have created the dymmy_function_plugin.inc.php under /usr/local/ispconfig/server/plugins-available root path. Then I have created symlink under /usr/local/ispconfig/server/plugins-enable through putty command. You can get idea from https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/creating-soft-link-or-symbolic-link/ for create symlink. As you know Ispconfig is event base so you just need to define your event under onload function then doo your code. I also want to inform you that if you call exit or die function that time cron was not run and your code not execute.